# UIActionSheet from UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to show a UIActionSheet when the user touches a button in a UIAlertView:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = ...
        [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
    }
}
```

When the action sheet is shown the alert view is still on the screen behind the action sheet, and when I touch a button in the action sheet - the action sheet disappears but the whole screen is dimmed with the alert view still on and I can't dismiss it.

I tried several things, such as showing the action sheet after a short delay or dismissing the alert view programmatically, but nothing worked. In the best case (dismissing the alert view programmatically) the alert view did disappear after a somewhat-strange transition but I got a "wait-fence failed to receive reply" error in the log when it did.

How can I show an action sheet from an alert view in an orderly manner?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this case, you should use

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

method rather than,

`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

so your code wil be:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = ...
        [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Just call [dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex%3aanimated%3a) method for UIAlertView

```
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = ...
    [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
}
```

Comment: When I call this method the alert view is removed with a somewhat-strange transition but I get a "wait-fence failed to receive reply" error in the log. I am looking for a clean solution.

Comment: And what is a 'somewhat-strange transition'? I have implemented this feature without any warnings. All works fine.

Comment: It means that the transition is not smooth. As if the alert view starts to disappear and immediately appears again and then disappears. And as I said, I also get an error message saying "wait-fence failed to receive reply", which is not exactly "works fine" (I am not willing to accept error messages even if the user doesn't see them). I did say that I already tried this solution and it is not acceptable. The correct answer is the one given by Ravin.